# NSMutableArray getting [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I really need some help...

When I try to get the number of cells for section using a NSMutableArray, I get [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d567e0

This happens when I use "rows = [[searchProfile objectAtIndex:section] count];"

Here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    // _________ Return the number of sections ________
    int sections =  0;

    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        sections = 2;
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        sections = [searchedProfile count];
    }
    return sections;
}


/* ------------------------------------------ Set The Number Of Cells for Each Section ------------------------------- */


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"2");

    // _________  Return the number of rows in the section. ________
    int rows = 0;

    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        if (section == 0) {
            rows = userProfile.count;}
        else {
            rows = profiles.count;}
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        rows = [[searchedProfile objectAtIndex:section]count];
    }
    return rows;
}
```

And the method that inserts strings into "searchedProfile" array:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    searchedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];
    searchedProfile = [NSMutableArray array];
    searchedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [searchedProfile removeAllObjects];
    [searchedData removeAllObjects];
    [searchedKeys removeAllObjects];


        NSDictionary *profile;

        for (profile in profiles)
        {
            NSString *birthname;
            NSString *currentname;
            NSString *photopath;
            NSDate *birthdate;

            for (birthname in profile)
            {
                birthname = [profile objectForKey:@"birthname"];
                currentname = [profile objectForKey:@"currentname"];
                photopath = [profile objectForKey:@"profilepic"];
                birthdate = [profile objectForKey:@"birthdate"];
                NSRange nameRange = [birthname rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

                if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    [searchedProfile addObject:birthname];
                    [searchedData setObject:birthname forKey:@"birthname"];
                    [searchedData setObject:currentname forKey:@"currentname"];
                    [searchedData setObject:photopath forKey:@"profilepic"];
                    [searchedData setObject:birthdate forKey:@"birthdate"];
                    if ([birthname isEqualToString:[profile objectForKey:@"birthname"]])
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    NSLog(@"SEARCHED PROFILES: %@", searchedProfile);
    NSLog(@"SEARCHED DATA:%@", searchedData);
    NSLog(@"SEARCHED KEYS:%@", searchedKeys);
    NSLog(@"count test: %d", searchedProfile.count);
    return YES;
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `count` method for NSArray's on an NSString, which is not allowed. You store NSStrings in the array `searchedProfile`, and it looks like you want to find out the length of a string. So instead of this:

```
    rows = [[searchedProfile objectAtIndex:section] count];
```

Do this:

```
    rows = [[searchedProfile objectAtIndex:section] length];
```

Comment: Doing that, fills my table view with the same result on many rows instead of showing one result per row..

Comment: What I want to do is this: take a value from a NSDictionary, store it in a string, store the string into a NSMutableArray (searchedProfile) use that array indexes to show the result (the string(s) from array) into a tableView.

Comment: @RazvanTanase if you are intentionally storing `NSString`s in `searchedProfile` then why are you calling `count` on them? I mean, what number are you trying to derive from them to calculate your number of rows?

Comment: @RazvanTanase - Carl is right. It's unclear what the purpose of calling 'count' on the strings is. Without the information, its hard to ascertain a solution for you.

Comment: No, this answer misses the point. He's calling this in numberOfRowsInSection, so he obviously wants the count of something, not the length of a string -- it's just that he has the "something wrong..

Comment: @rdelmar - On the contrary, the OP was originally asking how to fix the error he was getting, and my answer answers that. However, I acknowledge that you're correct in that my answer does not correct the logic of the code; it merely makes semantic and syntactic corrections.

Comment: Yes the answer is correct for my question. But it does not serves me well. I had a logic flaw :D.

Answer (score 0):

**[searchedProfile objectAtIndex:section]** will return string as the object in searchedProfile is string because this is how u added object before

```
 [searchedProfile addObject:birthname];
```

and **count** isnt the property defined for NSString. Anyways, it seems you want to return number of objects(i.e. number of birthnames stored in the searchedProfile array ) as the number of rows in the table, try this

```
rows = [searchedProfile count];
```

Answer (score 0):

Retain "searchedProfile" array by doing: searchedProfile = [[NSArray array] retain];